# Form does not load after DialogBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I have a dialog form:

```
_myLogin = new LoginPage(_myDriver);
_myLogin.ShowDialog();
```

and then I want to load another form

```
new RegularUser().Show();
```

Why dosn't my second form load?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply call new RegularUser().Show(); in the load method of your LoginPage form.

Answer (score 0):

Because your are showing your first form as a [Modal Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which must be closed or hidden before the user can continue working with the rest of the application, like a MessageBox.

You can instead use:

```
_myLogin.Show();
```

to display it as a Modeless form.

From the link:

> If a form is displayed as modal, the code following the ShowDialog method is not executed until the dialog box is closed. However, when a form is shown as modeless, the code following the Show method is executed immediately after the form is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the second form doesn't load because you've not closed first Modal dialog form.

`ShowDialog()` displays Modal dialog window

MSDN, [Form.ShowDialog Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx):

> When this method is called, the code following it is not executed
>   until after the dialog box is closed.

Try out using [Show()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show.aspx) method instead, so WIndow would be shown and all code after `Show()` call will be executed as well.

**PS:** Considering your form names, may be Modal dialog is the right decision for LoginForm? SO user see LoginForm, enter credentials, and only after the successfull authorization would be able access RegularUser form, I'm not sure about this because just assuming having only form names, but anyway Modal dialogs are excatly for such cases.